# Skipping blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that runs through my columns until the last row and formats based on the value. I've been trying to set my third condition so that it skips the blank cells, but cant figure out the formatting.

```
    Sub highlightLessThan()

Dim rg As Range
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
Set rg = Range("B2:AZ2", Range("B2:AZ2").End(xlDown))

'clear any existing conditional formatting
rg.FormatConditions.Delete

'define the rule for each conditional format
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, ".95")
Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, ".95")
Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotBetween, "0.0", "1.0")

'define the format applied for each conditional format
With cond1
.Interior.Color = vbGreen
.Font.Color = vbWhite
End With

With cond2
.Interior.Color = vbRed
.Font.Color = vbWhite
End With

With cond3
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
.Font.Color = vbRed
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sort order of your conditional formats. And @Harry showed us with [VBA Excel: Apply conditional formatting to BLANK cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143603/vba-excel-apply-conditional-formatting-to-blank-cells) how to apply conditional formatting to blank cells:

```
Option Explicit

Sub highlightLessThan()

Dim rg As Range
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
'Set rg = Range("B2:AZ2", Range("B2:AZ2").End(xlDown))
Set rg = Range("B2").CurrentRegion

'clear any existing conditional formatting
rg.FormatConditions.Delete

'define the rule for each conditional format
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlBlanksCondition)
Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, 0.95)
Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, 0.95)
'Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotBetween, "0.0", "1.0")
'Selection.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlBlanksCondition)

'define the format applied for each conditional format
With cond1
    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    .Font.Color = vbRed
End With

With cond2
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
End With

With cond3
    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to @Harry for his proposal at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143603/vba-excel-apply-conditional-formatting-to-blank-cells